# Why is my code working but infinitely printing?

Tags: python-3.x, function, csv

I am downloading two excel spreadsheets, one is a list of TLD's and their definitions the other is a list of the top one million websites. Part of my function is to find the top position of a particular TLD based off a user input. The code 'works' however it is printing the rank/key infinitely and I don't know why, any help is appreciated.

```
def parseCSV(tlds, top):

    tldDict = {
        " ":" "
    }

    topDict = {
        " ":" "
    }

    #opening CSV file using string from parameter
    file = open(r"C:\Users\bubba\OneDrive\Documents\Foundation Programming\tlds.csv", 'r')

    file2 = open(r"C:\Users\bubba\OneDrive\Documents\Foundation Programming\top 1m.csv", 'r')

    #iterating through file and splitting each line by comma
    #this is put into a dictionary
    for i in file.readlines():
        x=i.split(",")
        tldDict[x[0]]=x[1]
    file.close()

    for i in file2.readlines():
        x=i.split(",")
        topDict[x[0]]=x[1]
    file2.close()

    return [tldDict,topDict]

def getTopTLD(tld, tldDict, topDict):
    matched_keys = []
    for key, pair in topDict.items():
        if tld in pair:
            matched_keys.append(key) # Simple append statement 
            print('The position of this tld is:', min(matched_keys))
    return matched_keys

tldDict, topDict = parseCSV("tlds","top-1m")

while True:
    tld = input("Enter tld ")

    if tld == "exit":
        break

    getTopTLD(tld, tldDict, topDict)
```

console example:

```
Enter tld com
The position of this tld is: 1
The position of this tld is: 1
The position of this tld is: 1
The position of this tld is: 1
The position of this tld is: 1
```

I thought it might be the while loop but if I remove it the result is the same.

Comment: Is it *actually* printing infinitely, or just more than you expect? For it to be infinite, `topDict.items()` would need to return an infinite iterable, and I don't think it ever will.

Comment: That's a good point, probably not but it's going on for more than 2 minutes which is the longest I've waited

Comment: There are just over 550,000 URL's which finish with .com, so I would guess it would print it that many times

Comment: If you find yourself asking "why is X working but Y?", then X isn't working, and the question is just "why Y?"

Comment: Ya, it'll print once for each pair. What's your intended behavior?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I just want it to print 'The position of the TLD is: 1' ONCE

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point

Comment: You could just move the `print` outside of the `for key, pair` loop couldn't you?

Comment: Thanks. I'm suggesting that you apply that to your title

Comment: @Carcigenicate yep that worked, thank you, I'll try better before asking stupid questions again